# Getting 1920x1080 resolution or 16:9 aspect ratio on Ubuntu or Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, resolution, vmware, aspect-ratio

I am running Ubuntu and Linux Mint in VMWare. In the display settings, none of the 16:9 aspect ratio resolutions are available, including the commonly used 1920x1080 resolution. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 62):

Enter the following commands in a terminal to enable 1920x1080 resolution:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080
```

This will set your display resolution to 1920x1080 and also enable several other 16:9 aspect ratio resolutions in the display settings.

Remember that you may have to enable full screen mode in VMWare before these resolutions become selectable.

Comment: I was having this problem and found the solution on this webpage: http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/07/1920x1080-ubuntu-vmware/

I'm sharing this question and answer because it seems to be a frequent problem experienced by people running any kind of Linux distribution in a virtual machine. I really don't understand how the command works, so if someone would be willing to explain what the various numbers mean (besides the obvious resolution dimensions) that would be most welcome.

Comment: Hi Brain, what should be done for 1366x768 resolution ?

Comment: Worth noting that you should identify your display first, using `xrandr`. Mine is `VBOX0` instead of `Virtual1`.

Comment: It worked! I could kiss you :)

Comment: Oh. It goes back to a small resolution after a restart :(

Comment: As Manu mentioned, these changes are lost when you reboot the machine, however, here is a blog post that explains how to update a config file to persist these changes even after a reboot: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/877

Comment: As tobibeer suggested in another answer, and as an alternative to changing the config files as I commented above, I saved these 3 lines to a shell script (1920x1080.sh), made it executable, and each time I boot up I go to a terminal window and run "sudo bash 1920X1080.sh" and it sets the resolution perfectly.

Comment: I met a `X Error of failed request: BadName (named color or font does not exist)` error, and according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3414850  , I changed the mode name, 1920x1080 -> 1920*1080, then it works, for example,  the first command  is `xrandr --newmode "1920*1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`  .

Comment: This worked for me 2020-11-11 on Zorin OS Core 15.3 (Ubuntu base) under VMware Workstation 15.

Comment: Above commands failed for me, any tips?
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  141 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  57

Answer (score 10):

@InvalidBrainException's answer is great. In addition, in order to it make it permanent and prevent running commands on each restart, you can write the following configs into file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Virtual1"
    Modeline "p1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "p1920x1080"
EndSection
```

Comment: If you need to improve on it, it isn’t perfect, is it?    :-)    ⁠

Comment: This is amazing, and exactly what I was looking for.  Takes effect after reboot, and effectively sets the resolution for the login screen!

Comment: I don't have /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d ...

Comment: Yes, it helps, thanks a lot!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, when Wayland is used, this does not work even when changing the Identifier to XWAYLAND0. If Wayland is disabled, it works without any problem (with Virtual1 identifier).

Answer (score 3):

@mhsekhavat Years later... Ubuntu 20.04 on vbox 6.1.

1. Stick the [10-monitor.conf](https://superuser.com/a/1255916/644034) in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
2. Reboot
3. 1920 x 1080 should now be available in the Ubuntu Settings > Screen Display
4. Select it and Apply and Keep Changes

Now on reboot it should remember!

Comment: does not work. I cannt see it there

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu in VirtualBox, I had this issue, and the issue with the resolution being forgotten on restart (reported elsewhere). Both issues were fixed for me by following method 2 in:

https://linuxhint.com/change-resolution-of-a-linux-vm-in-virtualbox/

In summary it says that after installing dkms you should "insert" and run the host specific Guest Additions CD image then restart.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on Virtualbox:

```
sudo cvt 1920 1080 60    
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Answer (score -2):

You can take the script from [InvalidBrainException](https://superuser.com/users/102639/invalidbrainexception) and...

- create a 1920x1080.sh file
- make it executable
- add it as a startup script so that it is run on system startup

Otherwise you'll have to run these lines after each startup manually.